# Switch Function and Invalid Use of Null in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I have a query where I want the result to return the DOB for an individual according to their "Sequential Number". It is returning the individual's name correctly, but not their correct DOB. I am using a MAX function because I need all of this data on one row and if I don't use it, I get multiple rows if there are more than one dependents associated with an employee.

However, it is pulling the Max DOB if there are multiple dependents and not the one corresponding to D.SequentialNumber=1, which is not what I need. What am I missing here?

Below is a mini sample of my query:

```
SELECT EIN.EIN, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name, 
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1,D.DepFirstName)) AS Cov24_First_Name, 
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1,D.DepLastName)) AS Cov24_Last_Name, 
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1 AND nz(D.DepDOB) > 0, "")) AS Cov24_SSN,
 Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1 and D.CoveredIndividualSSN >0, "", d.DepDOB)) AS Cov24_DOB

FROM (tblEmp AS E LEFT JOIN tblEIN AS EIN ON E.EIN = EIN.EIN) LEFT JOIN tblDep AS D ON E.Emp_SSN = D.ResponsibleIndividualSSN
GROUP BY EIN.EIN, E.First_Name, E.Middle_Name, E.Last_Name;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you on MS Access?

Comment: Yes I am on Access @Martin

Comment: IIF has two-part, Return value for true condition and return value for the false condition: IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )

Comment: Is the query supposed to return information about dependents as well, or should it be isolated to the employee only?

Comment: Unlike some other languages, `IIf` in Access always requires truepart and falsepart, even if falsepart returns nothing. See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Comment: @JennaTerral; please provide more info about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the conditions are backwards and you might want:

```
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1 and D.CoveredIndividualSSN >0, d.DepDOB, NULL)) AS Cov24_DOB
```

Comment: I am needing the DOB returned only if there is not a SSN

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the query :

```
SELECT EIN.EIN, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name, 
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1,D.DepFirstName, "")) AS Cov24_First_Name, 
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1,D.DepLastName, "")) AS Cov24_Last_Name, 
Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1 AND nz(D.DepDOB) > 0, "", 0)) AS Cov24_SSN,
 Max(IIf(D.SequentialNumber=1 and D.CoveredIndividualSSN >0, "", d.DepDOB, "")) AS Cov24_DOB

FROM (tblEmp AS E LEFT JOIN tblEIN AS EIN ON E.EIN = EIN.EIN) LEFT JOIN tblDep AS D ON E.Emp_SSN = D.ResponsibleIndividualSSN
GROUP BY EIN.EIN, E.First_Name, E.Middle_Name, E.Last_Name;
```

Comment: What are you not sure about? It works, I just condensed it down because the full thing is huge

Comment: Please clarify what you're not sure about. If you're not sure if about OP's original query, please state what you found that was incorrect. If you're unsure about the solution you're providing, consider testing it and proofreading your code to make sure it's an accurate answer.

Comment: Not sure because I have not the sample data, So please accept as answer if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if query is supposed to be scoped to only the employee with SequentialNumber = 1, or if query should handle all dependents. For a better answer, please clarify on the intent of the query, as we may be able to save downstream steps with a better understanding.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        EIN.EIN
        ,E.First_Name
        ,E.Last_Name
        ,D.DepFirstName AS Cov24_First_Name
        ,D.DepLastName AS Cov24_Last_Name
        ,D.ResponsibleIndividualSSN AS Cov24_SSN
        ,CASE
            WHEN NULLIF(D.CoveredIndividualSSN,'') IS NULL THEN D.DepDOB
        END AS Cov24_DOB
FROM    tblEmp AS E
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEIN AS EIN ON E.EIN = EIN.EIN
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDep AS D ON E.Emp_SSN = D.ResponsibleIndividualSSN
WHERE   D.SequentialNumber = 1
```

Comment: It is intended to continue with additional sequential numbers but once I have this first part, then I can apply it to the rest